# How to properly send a JSON CURL to Slack?

Tags: php, json, curl, slack

I have a CURL code that I use to integrate with `GetResponse` and I thought ill go ahead and copy/paste it for slack too. For some reason there are no errors at all yet slack is empty of requests (a POST to this URL with Postman works just fine). What am I missing? I couldn't find a solution the whole night.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function slackReporting($data)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXX/XXXX/XXXXXX');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_exec($ch);
}

$slackReporting_data = array(
    'text' => "`New Lead` `+34 today`.",
    'username' => "Leads",
    'mrkdwn' => true
);

$slackReporting_res = json_decode(slackReporting($slackReporting_data));

$slackReporting_error = "";
if(empty($slackReporting_res->error)){
    echo "OK";
} else {
    $slackReporting_error = $slackReporting_res->error->message;
}
echo $slackReporting_error;
?>
```

I always get an OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you din't return anything from function so you are getting nothing inside `$slackReporting_res` .Do like below:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function slackReporting($data)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXX/XXXX/XXXXXX');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $content  = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
       echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);exit;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
$slackReporting_data = array(
    'text' => "`New Lead` `+34 today`.",
    'username' => "Leads",
    'mrkdwn' => true
);
$slackReporting_res = json_decode(slackReporting($slackReporting_data));

var_dump ($slackReporting_res); //check output and work accordingly
?>
```

And now Op's got error and solved through this link(mentioned by OP in comment):-

[PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: With your example I get `NULL`.

Comment: `Warning: curl_errno(): 2 is not a valid cURL handle resource in on line 16` I'm confused now.

Comment: Awesome! It was an error with the SSL `Request Error:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` and I've fixed it with the help of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: @Ricardo  glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to use slack with `curl`

```
<?php
define('SLACK_WEBHOOK', 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/yyy/zzz');
function slack($txt) {
  $msg = array('text' => $txt);
  $c = curl_init(SLACK_WEBHOOK);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('payload' => json_encode($msg)));
  curl_exec($c);
  curl_close($c);
}
?>
```

Snippet taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/urigoren/be3190dd8a1d1d84994e1c066f2845b0)